# Purpose of JBoss tables

Tags: jboss5.x

Can anyone point me in the direction of some documentation (or provide the information here) about the following tables, created by JBoss 5.1.0 when it starts up?

I know what they are for at a high level, and know why they are there, but I could do with some lower-level documentation about each table's purpose.

The tables are:

- hilosequences
- timers
- jbm_counter
- jbm_dual
- jbm_id_cache
- jbm_msg
- jbm_msg_ref
- jbm_postoffice
- jbm_role
- jbm_tx
- jbm_user

I know that the first two are associated with uuid-key-generator and the EJB Timer Service respectively, while the rest are associated with JBoss Messaging. What I want to know is something along the lines of "jmg_msg stores each message when it is created...", that kind of thing.

Thanks

Rich

ps: I originally [asked](https://serverfault.com/questions/153594/purpose-of-jboss-tables) this question at ServerFault but didn't get a response

Answer (score 1):

`hilosequences` is used by the `uuid-key-generator.sar` which provides the `jboss:service=KeyGeneratorFactory,type=HiLo` service, which basically allows you to have UUID keys consistently across all aplications of an instance

`timers` is used by `ejb2-timer-service.xml`, a legacy timer service

and the `jbm*` tables are used by JBoss Messaging (JMS) to store messages, queues, etc, which is why it's **strongly recommended** to change the DB from the default (Hypersonic) to a production ready one